# Different vertical spacing when applying local formatting via setspace in a new environment

Tags: formatting, paragraphs

I am trying to create a new environment, which alters some paragraph formatting. I thought I could achieve that via `setspace` but there is a problem with vertical spaces before a paragraph of interest: `\singlespacing` seems to add a fixed space independent to what is a document set to, while `\setstretch{}` keeps the same space between a previous paragraph and the one being changed as what is defined inside the environment. I can't figure out how to get the same vertical spaces before and after this paragraph.

I made the MWE which shows and put screenshots based on both settings: for the document and for the environment line-spacing. I was hoping to show that there are different vertical spaces added or removed by commands. There are four screenshots grouped in the table below in the following order

- rows represent the same document line-spacing (single- or triple-)
- columns represent a command I used to set single-spacing inside the environment (either via `\singlespacing` or `\setstretch{1.0}`.

As an example, the second row and the first column represent a triple line-spacing of the whole document and single-spacing of a paragraph, which in this case is altered via `\singlespacing`.

Apart from a consistent vertical spacing before and after the paragraph, I would also like the size to follow a global document line-spacing, which would grow or get smaller. I hope it all makes sense.

Thanks

---

The table:

|  | `\singlespacing` | `\stretch{1.0}` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `\stretch{1.0}` | [image] | [image] |
| `\stretch{3.0}` | [image] | [image] |

---

The MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
    \setstretch{3.0}
\usepackage{lipsum}


%%% Directquote
\newlength\dquoteleftmargin     \setlength{\dquoteleftmargin}{\parindent}
\newlength\dquoterightmargin    \setlength{\dquoterightmargin}{0pt}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{directquote}{O{\parindent} o b}{%
    \ifblank{#1}
        {\setlength{\leftskip}{\parindent}}
        {\setlength{\leftskip}{#1}}
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\setlength{\rightskip}{0pt}}%
        {\ifblank{#2}
            {\setlength{\rightskip}{0pt}}
            {\setlength{\rightskip}{#2}}
        }%
    % \setstretch{1.0} #3
    \singlespacing #3
    \par
}{}
\def\exampledq{\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravi-da mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna (Someone 2021, p. 21).}
%%% END Directquote


%%% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

%%% SECTION single spacing
\section{Formatting inside a new environment }

An example of a custom paragraph formatting inside a new environment:

\begin{directquote}%
    \exampledq
\end{directquote}%

\noindent continuation with ordinary paragraph settings.

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```